# Why isn't space deallocated after deleting all rows from a clustered table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

Today one of our queries has gone crazy. It was hanging for more than an hour before I killed the process.

```
UPDATE  tc
SET tc.Status   = 0
FROM    #RC_Task_Calc   AS tc
CROSS
APPLY   (   SELECT  TOP 1
            _tt.CalcStamp
        ,   _tt.TrDateInto
        FROM    dbo.TableName   AS _tt
        WHERE   _tt.TableId = tc.TableId
        AND _tt.EventKind   = tc.EventKind
        AND _tt.DayDate <= @DayDate
        AND _tt.Status  = 1
        ORDER
        BY  _tt.DayDate DESC
    )   AS tt
WHERE   tc.CalcStamp    = tt.CalcStamp
AND tc.TrDateInto   = tt.TrDateInto
```

It was expected to perform about 600k loops to `dbo.TableName` which had no rows. But something went wrong.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableName](
    [Id] [dbo].[TBigInt] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TableId] [dbo].[TRowId] NOT NULL,
    [EventKind] [dbo].[TRowId] NOT NULL,
    [DayDate] [dbo].[TDate] NOT NULL,
    [CalcStamp] [varbinary](8) NULL,
    [TrDateInto] [dbo].[TDate] NULL,
    [Flag] [dbo].[TFlag] NOT NULL,
    [Status] [dbo].[TTinyInt] NOT NULL,
    [Stamp] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    [CreatorId] [dbo].[TRowId] NOT NULL,
    [Created] [dbo].[TDateTime] NOT NULL,
    [ChangerId] [dbo].[TRowId] NOT NULL,
    [Changed] [dbo].[TDateTime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [ITableNameId] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
),
 CONSTRAINT [ITableNameIdentity] UNIQUE CLUSTERED 
(
    [TableId] ASC,
    [EventKind] ASC,
    [DayDate] ASC
)
)
```

I saw in properties of `dbo.TableName` (using SSMS) such information:

> Data space ~ 129 MB
>
> Index space ~ 49 MB
>
> Row count = 0

After rebuilding indexes on the table the query completed in less than a second

```
ALTER INDEX all ON [dbo].[TableName] REBUILD
```

I'm aware of removing all data from the table using a `DELETE` command yesterday. But why did I have to rebuild indexes so that the space was deallocated?

The table is clustered so it shouldn't have heaps' problems on deletion. All pages should have been empty after deletion because all rows was removed. I thought it could be linked to mixed extents, but `is_mixed_page_allocation_on=0` for that database.

So could someone explain me what I missed here? Why those pages weren't deallocated? Or maybe I'm a victim of some misconception about the deletion from clustered table process.

> Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU4) (KB4464106) - 13.0.5233.0 (X64) 
>     Nov  3 2018 00:01:54    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
>     Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server
>   2016 Standard 10.0  (Build 14393: )

Comment: Please check your table DDL, it seems to be incorrect.

Comment: @Learning_DBAdmin, it's here just to provide indexing information, on real data we have default constraints and created user-defined data types (TBigInt, TRowId and so on). DDL is correct, I can successfully create such a table.

Comment: @DenisRubashkin - can you [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) that shows this behavior?  Also, how long between the deleting of rows and the checking of space used?  My understanding is that, even with a clustered index, the deallocation of pages occurs in a background process unless the `tablock` hint is included.

Comment: I am still not able to reproduce the behavior on our test environment but I go on trying. There were more than 12 hours between the deletion and the `update` query.

Comment: @ScottHodgin, thanks to your comment I paid attention on the table's properties window after deletion. You are absolutely right that deallocation doesn't occur immediately after the `delete` command finished. But that process was noticed to take no more than just couple minutes on the test environment. I doubt that hours of waiting for deallocation is normal even for a highly loaded production environment. So, some additional info about the background process would be appreciated.

Comment: @DenisRubashkin - do you have any trace flags enabled in production?  Just wondering if the Ghost Cleanup process isn't running.  See information about [Ghost cleanup process guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/ghost-record-cleanup-process-guide?view=sql-server-2017), specifically the section _Disable the ghost cleanup_.  I don't know if you're in this situation or not - just thought I'd pass the information along.

Comment: Do you have Read Committed Snapshot Isolation, or Snapshot Isolation enabled?

Comment: @ScottHodgin, It isn't the case but very useful to know, thanks.

Comment: @ErikDarling, Snapshot Isolation and Read Committed Snapshot are enabled on the database

Comment: I know that this can happen with [heaps](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/01/heaps-deletes-optimistic-isolation-levels/), so maybe it's the case here too.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce described behavior. I created the same table, fill it with data and then delete all rows.

After deleting I had a look at indexes:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(), OBJECT_ID('TableName_Test'), -1, NULL, 'DETAILED')
```

Results (I hid columns which don't matter):

[image]

Thank you,  Scott Hodgin and Erik Darling, you both were partly right and direct me to  the right way in my researches. The issue occurs because Ghost Cleanup process can't clean the version ghost records.

The behavior is similar to one described here: [Problem With Too Many version_ghost_records](https://michaeljswart.com/2017/08/problem-with-too-many-version_ghost_records/).

Unfortunately, I can't call exactly what is root cause of being the versioned rows still held. I have not found any long transaction on any database which could cause it.

Index rebuilding and sometimes (as told in the article linked above) server restart help to solve the issue.